# Datagrid  is not saving the changes user applies

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having troubles in getting a grid to work:

*I want to let users add rows but when the program is compiled the `CanUserAddRows` is set to false.* - SOLVED

Another problem I'm facing is when the user edits the grid, it isn't applying what has been changed; although the delete is working fine.

How can I solve this?

```
public ObservableCollection<BolaInfo> bolas;
public IniciaSim()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.bolas = new ObservableCollection<BolaInfo>();
}

private void Introduzir_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (rendering)
    {
        plotCanvas.Children.Clear();
        CompositionTarget.Rendering -= RenderFrame;
        rendering = false;
    }

    DataGrid dados = new DataGrid();
    dados.Width = plotCanvas.ActualWidth;
    dados.Height = plotCanvas.ActualHeight;
    dados.ColumnWidth = 128;
    dados.IsReadOnly = false;
    dados.IsEnabled = true;
    dados.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dados.CanUserResizeColumns = false;
    dados.CanUserReorderColumns = false;
    dados.CanUserAddRows = true;
    dados.CanUserDeleteRows = true;
    dados.ItemsSource = bolas;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if BolaInfo class has a contructor without parameters. I think you can only add rows automatically if the class can create a new instance without parameters.

Comment: Well first part of the problem is solved, now I have the problem of not submitting the data that is introduced in the grid.

Comment: I had to put is some cases Binding Mode=TwoWay for column binding, but I didn't used AutoGenerateColumns.

Comment: The thing is I'm using a datagrid for user input but wanted to restrict only for two values. If I use TwoWay and just declare the two fields I want the user to use, it doesn't set automatically the other values, so for now I'm using the AutoGenerateColumns because I crossed around another problem not grid related. I fix one problem, I find another one ahah..

Comment: you can check (I'm not sure) if ItemsSource get updated with user values, and if it does you can update BolaInfo collection with the new values manually